# Why is this if/else always true?

Tags: perl

Whatever color the input is it returns "green" :(

```
sub next_traffic_lights {
  my ($x) = @_;
  if ($x == "red") { 
    return "green";
  } 
  elsif ($x == "green") {
    return "yellow";
  } else {
    return "red";
  }
 }
```

Comment: If you had used `use strict; use warnings;`, Perl would have told you.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl `==` means [*numerical equivalence*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) where `eq` is *string equivalence*. You just need to flip those `==` to `eq` to do the right comparisons.

Both `"red"` and `"green"` are equal to zero numerically, so they're considered identical here using numerical comparison.

When writing code like this you should steer towards a lookup table anyway, as this is basically a simple state machine:

```
my %next_light = (
  "red" => "green",
  "yellow" => "red",
  "green" => "yellow"
);

sub next_traffic_lights {
  return $next_light{$_[0]};
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Anecdote: In Germany things are much more complicated. The traffic lights go "red" → "red&yellow" → "green" → "yellow" → "red".